# ¿Como pongo restricciones dentro de un complextype en xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema

Necesito que nombre tenga un maximo de 40 caracteres pero no se muy bien como añadir esa restricción ya que estoy intentando añadirlo poniendo simpletype y me da el siguiente error "El tipo de elemento "xs:element" debe ir seguido de una de estas especificaciones de atributo: ">" o "/>". [13] "

```
 <xs:element name="sociedad">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="N_sociedad" maxOccurs="150" />
           <xs:element name="nombre"">
               <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
               <xs:maxLength value="40" />
               </xs:restriction>
               </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="anyo_fundacion"/>
           <xs:element name="presidente">
               <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:element name="n_socio"/>
                       <xs:element name="nif"/>
                       <xs:element name="nombre"/>
                       <xs:element name="apellidos"/>
                   </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `xs:minLenght` y `xs:maxLength` para delimitar el campo `nombre`, de esta forma puedes indicar que tenga el mínimo que tu necesites y el máximo de 40.

Modifico la parte del elemento nombre con dos propuestas:

## Solución 1 (usando minLenght y maxLength)

```
<xs:element name="nombre">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:minLength value="1"/>
         <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

## Solución 2 (usando minInclusive y maxInclusive)

```
<xs:element name="nombre">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
         <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
         <xs:maxInclusive value="40"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```